# How can I interact with a Corda node via RPC, using curl?

Tags: shell, curl, rpc, corda

Hope all are safe and well! I asked this question on Slack but was suggested I ask here.

I have a Corda 4.3 compatibility zone setup using the `bootstrapper`, and I have setup my `node.conf` file user section as below:

```
rpcUsers = [
    { 
        username=user1, 
        password=password1, 
        permissions=[ ALL ] 
    }
]
```

My RPC settings are:

```
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10201"
    adminAddress="localhost:10202"
}
```

And I can see that the port is open:

```
# nc -v localhost 10201 
localhost (127.0.0.1:10201) open
^Cpunt!
```

My questions are:

1. is it possible to connect to a Corda node and execute API commands using RPC?
2. by API commands I mean the same as if I was connecting to Corda shell, is this the case?

Thanks,

Viv

Answer (score 0):

SSH is disabled, by default, you could enable it with the below settings in node.conf file.

```
sshd {
    port = <portNumber>
}
```

Once enabled you could connect to the node using SSH and execute all the command that could normally execute from the node's shell.

Use the below command to connect to the node:

```
ssh -p [portNumber] [host] -l [user]
```

For more details on node shell refer the docs here:  https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html

Comment: Thank you. I have enabled SSH, so that might be an option.

Comment: so looks like with SSH enabled, it is the last service component to start, AFTER all the participant node service components have started, so checking we have an open and listening socket might well do the trick for the for the level of fidelity/accuracy I require .... 

If not, then lifecycle monitoring will have to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SpringBoot webserver like in [this example](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/spring-webserver):

1. You create an [RPC connection](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-java/src/main/java/net/corda/server/NodeRPCConnection.java); which uses the RPC user credential that you identified in your `node.conf`.
2. The RPC connection gets injected into the controller where you define your API's.
3. The injected RPC connection exposes a `proxy` that you can use for many things including starting flows and querying the vault. Have a look at the [StandardController](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-java/src/main/java/net/corda/server/controllers/StandardController.java) example to see various RPC interactions with the node. You can add your own API's to the template [CustomController](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-java/src/main/java/net/corda/server/controllers/CustomController.java).
4. The [webserver](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-java/src/main/java/net/corda/server/Server.java) is a simple SpringBoot application.
5. When you start the webserver with this [Gradle task](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-java/build.gradle), it will inject the RPC connection into the controller and expose your API's on the port that you supply in [application.properties](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-java/src/main/resources/application.properties) file.
6. Now that the webserver is running, you can call your API's either using CURL or Postman.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm running Corda within a container, and adding the SpringBoot webserver application will make the container resource footprint much heavier for (as far as I can see at present) not a lot of utility ...

Let me put it this way, I am trying to ascertain that the Corda service has started before executing some shell scripts within a container, can you please recommend a better/alternate way to do this?

Comment: I'm reading your thread on Slack, and I understand that you want to emit some events when your node is fully started. Corda 4.4 has a new feature where you create a service and inside that service you can register for Node lifecycle events; once you register for those events, you can listen to a certain event (e.g. node fully started) and execute an action when it's dispatched. So in your case, that will translate to emitting notifications that the node is fully started using your node lifecycle events observer.

Comment: Read **Corda Service Lifecycle Monitoring** section in [my article](https://blog.b9lab.com/whats-new-and-exciting-in-corda-4-4-6b02c1b7d734), and see if that's something that you can use to achieve your goal.